# Why is "plaid" pronounced "plad"?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Why is there an 'ai' in *plaid* if it is pronounced "plad"?  That's a word that used to trip me up when I was a little tyke.  (*This* time, unlike [my previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36188/10041), I hope I'm right in saying that this word is an oddity in having an 'ai' pronounced as 'a'.)

Comment: But don't confuse with Welsh *plaid* /plaɪd/ meaning *side* or *political party*.

Comment: Tangential comment: "Plaid" appears to be a much more common word in the US than in Britain (even Scotland): what Americans call "plaid", we usually call "tartan".

Comment: @Colin Fine - Quite. Here in the US I have heard "tartan" used, but in the clothing industry you usually see them describe that pattern as plaid. My wife may even be able to describe a difference between the two words, but as a meer male I don't see one.

Comment: A meer male is like a meercat?

Comment: I thought that a plaid was a tartan cloak worn over the shoulder as part of parade dress.

Comment: Did none of you know a girl with hair in plaits - and skirt with pleats who plied you with alcohol while using a com-plic-ated ploy to per-plex you?

Comment: While the word is an oddity, it's not quite unique: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72432/british-pronunciation-of-plait

Comment: Plaid as in maid as in the line of a song 'He wrapped me in his plaide'. But they're both from another time - It's tartan nowadays in Scotland.

Comment: A meercat is like a meerkat?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because it's not English — it's from the Gaelic word for *blanket*.

According to [Gaelic pronunciation](http://www.musesrealm.net/celtic/language.html), "ai" in old Irish is a short 'a' as in *gather*.

Comment: The Scottish pronounce it so that it rhymes with maid, that is nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Just like to point out two things:

Plaid comes from [Scottish Gaelic:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plaid)

> 1505–15; < Scots Gaelic plaide  blanket, plaid

According to the site that @Martin Beckett provided, Scottish Gaelic [pronounces "ai", as short `a`.](http://www.musesrealm.net/celtic/language.html#sg)

Comment: But it doesn't say what C16 scots pronounced it as

Comment: Scots Gaelic was still in use C16

Comment: English isn't the only language to have undergone pronunciation changes.

Comment: @Thursagen - I meant the pronunciation site didn't give a specific 'old' Scots pronunciation as it did with Irish.